# not getting jre system library in maven project in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image: here is img]

Not getting java support after creating maven project in eclipse
when maven project created I am not getting src/main/java,src/test/java and jre system libraries folders. i am following steps to create new project
steps to create

** maven project: File-->new-->project-->select maven project-->next-->select create a simple project-->next-->give project id and artifact id-->finish.**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>MavenProject1</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenProject1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>MavenProject1</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: There are errors. Don't ignore them. Look into the _Problems_ view.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [You first posted a cropped screenshot showing that there are errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBWzE.png), [now there are only warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjzty.png). Did you right-click the project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._ after fixing those errors? Please show your `pom.xml`. Did you specified the Java version and the encoding in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @howlger please see the updated post I have updated.

Comment: What you saying and what you show differ. Right-click the project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._ Are sure you want to use outdated Java 7 in your project (not recommended)? If yes, make sure to have configured a Java 7 JDK in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you wont get that. Its just a basic, very simple maven project that eclipse creates for you, so that you can structure the project as you like.

You now have 2 options:

1. create all the structuring by yourself
2. Create a new maven project and instead of selecting `select create a simple project`, select `from archetype`, and from there you can you can select what you like (Ex: maven-archetype-quickstart ) according to what you like.

For more info on setting up maven project with arch type search in youtube. You will get a lot of video tutorials.

Comment: I tried that steps also but its not working can you please elaborate more, I have updated my post. its getting after following above steps.